# JRuby Classpath Issue with class dependencies

Tags: jar, jruby

I have some compiled code inside my_project/java/classes. I also have all the libraries for that code in my_project/java/lib as jars.

For some reason I cannot get the jars inside that lib to be available so the java classes can access them.

Details: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5219067

As you can see, I can interact with the library I'm trying to import. It definitely there, and it's on the classpath.

I've also tried without success several times now to try and build a 'fat' jar with all the dependencies bundled inside of it, using several ways, primarily Eclipse's Export with dependencies packaged inside the jar, and the jar index shows that it has all the dependencies as matlabcontrol/** included the InvokationException class just as the error shows.

When I imported the class it was giving me trouble with in the Program.java file, then upon calling that same Matlab.initialize() function, I got an error for a different class. So I'm wondering if I'm not building the classes correctly, so the "import 'matlabcontrol.*" aren't being resolved properly.